# Google Authenticator on Nginx

Tags: nginx, pam, google-authenticator

I built Nginx with ngx_http_auth_pam_module and edited Nginx configurations and `/etc/pam.d/nginx` like this

Part of virtual host setting

```
location / {
    root   /projects/admin;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    auth_pam "Google Authenticator Code Required";
    auth_pam_service_name "nginx";
}
```

`/etc/pam.d/nginx`

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

Why can't I authorize by the Google Authenticator? Please help me.

Comment: Is the PAM module even configured?

Comment: Also, we don't even know what the problem is, does NGINX not prompt for the password, does PAM validation fail... This question doesn't even ask a half decent question